# Electron + Angular CLI how to package dist with electron-packager

Tags: angular, electron, angular-cli, electron-packager

I have an `Electron` and `Anguarjs CLI` app that I want to distribute.

After running `ng build --prod` I get a `dist` directory that is ~1Mb.
However after running `electron-packager .` the app is ~350Mb.

I have my electron `main.js` setup to point to the `index.html` of the `dist`, but I am guessing that the package command doesn't use the `dist` to build the app but rather the bloated dev version.
I have tried running `electron-packager .` from within `dist`, it still creates a huge app.

Is there a way to package the `dist` folder?
Should I rather be using a different packaging tool?

My aim is to package the app so that doesn't nuke band width to distribute.

Comment: The dist directory does not contain node_modules. Electron packages your app (from dist) together with required code from node_modules and node environment. This is why your image is much bigger than dist directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `electron-packager` [readme.md](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/readme.md):

> Be careful not to include node_modules you don't want into your final
>   app. If you put them in the devDependencies section of package.json,
>   by default none of the modules related to those dependencies will be
>   copied in the app bundles.

The angular CLI uses `webpack` internally to bundle your code. To reduce the electron package size, whatever is already bundled by webpack that's currently in your `dependencies` section of your `package.json` can go in the `devDependencies` section instead. That'll prevent `electron-packager` from bundling any `node_modules` code you aren't actually referencing due to webpack having already extracted it when bundling the output chunks in your `dist` folder.

Comment: Good suggestion. I will need to take time to make sure I strip out any unnecessary includes. I wonder if the Angular includes aren't the culprits. I don't have that much packages included.

Comment: Current dependencies: angular - animations,common,compiler,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,router
other - bootstrap,core-js,eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker,jquery,machine-uuid,moment,ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker,ngx-electron,ngx-select-ex,rxjs,zone.js

Comment: I think webpack is already bundling all of that angular code in the vendor bundle, so it's a likely candidate for moving to `devDependencies`.